# angular show inputs base checkbox ng-model make inputs unreachable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please help, I have the following code

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" ng-model="Status" />
    <span ng-bind="Title"></span>
</div>
<div id="div1" ng-show="Status">
    <span ng-bind="SpanTitle" ></span>
    <input type="text" id="txtLastName" 
       ng-model="LastName"
       ng-click="LastNameClick()"
       ng-blur="LastNameOut()"
       name="txtLastName" />
</div>
```

and when checkbox is being checked the div1 is shown but the input text cannot be clicked or written.

Any idea please?

**Edit**: Added controller from user's comment

```
function DController($scope) {
    var defaultInputText = "hello";
    $scope.Title = "check";
    $scope.SpanTitle = "Span";
    $scope.Status = false;
    $scope.LastName = defaultInputText;
    $scope.LastNameClick = function () {
        if ($scope.LastName ==defaultInputText) {
            $scope.LastName = "";
        }
    }
    $scope.LastNameOut = function () {
        if ($scope.LastName.length == 0) {
            $scope.LastName = defaultInputText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post your controller?

Comment: Seems to work fine here. (see http://jsfiddle.net/fL80gLoo/)

Comment: Yes I saw thank you. 
Buy the way I forgot to mention that it's only happans in ie

Comment: the controller

function DController($scope) {

    var defaultInputText = "hello";
    $scope.Title = "check";
    $scope.SpanTitle = "Span";
    $scope.Status = false;
    $scope.LastName = defaultInputText;

    $scope.LastNameClick = function () {
        if ($scope.LastName ==defaultInputText) {
            $scope.LastName = "";
        }
    }

    $scope.LastNameOut = function () {
        if ($scope.LastName.length == 0) {
            $scope.LastName = defaultInputText;
        }
    }
 
}

Answer (score 0):

From code, that you have provided, I can suggest, that problem can be in css. May be some elements overlap the input.